# Android Picasso Crop and FitX

Tags: android, crop, picasso

So im having troubles trying to figure out how to accomplish certain image transformations using picasso library. I am not sure the build-in picasso methods allow me to do the following, which i need help to accomplish:

- I have a recyclerview with cards as child layouts. What i want to do is to set a background image for each card, loaded from an url.
- The images are too big, so if i have to do the following:

-- the first vertical part of the image is the one i'm interested in. So i need to crop the image at half (vertically). Then fit to the x-y of the imageview, which are fixed dimentions. How to accomplish that with picasso?